# DatetimePicker.Value Property Changes After Setting MaxDate

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I have `DateTimePicker` in my Windows forms application. When I watch `DateTimePicker.Value` property it returns `23/6/2015 11:23:17 PM` which is the correct value.

The problem appears when I set `MaxDate` property to the `Value`, then `Value` property returns as `23/6/2015 12:00:00 Am` and it's the wrong answer.

So how can I get the correct one (`23/6/2015 11:23:17 PM`) after setting `MaxDate` Property?

here my load event which set maxvalue to datetimepicker

```
private void Models_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

and this my property

```
public DateTime Date
{ 
    get
    { 
        return dateTimePicker1.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to get/set the values?

Comment: public DateTime Date { get { return dateTimePicker1.Value; } set { dateTimePicker1.Value = value; } }                                                                                                            private void Models_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

Comment: The text of your question does not match your snippets at all.  The simple explanation is that you actually do what you say, it is a Date-Or-TimePicker.  A date selected by the user doesn't have a time.

Comment: control called DateTimePicker if you notice it should return date with time but when i set maxDate property it return only date .got it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange.
Try this:

```
private void Models_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dtNow = new DateTime();
    dtNow = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;
    dateTimePicker1.Value = dtNow;
}
```